# python: RE-based substitution

Tags: python

There is a string in the following format:

```
name='6000_12_lig_cne_697'
```

I need to substitute '*12*' to '*something*' using regular expression, obtaining new variable:

```
final_name=re.sub(r'_12_', '_something_', name)
```

How I could adopt this RE to general case that will recognize all patterns, matching a number between the first and the second _ in the variable name (e.g. the substitution part may be: *13*,  *24* etc)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Specify what exactly means "a number"? Exactly two digits? At least one digit? Can it be negative? Only integer numbers? Can it start with a `0`? Is it guaranteed that there is only one number between underlines in the input string? Maybe `r'_[1-9][0-9]*_'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "number" means "a bunch of digits 0 to 9", what you're looking for is `[0-9]+`, so:

```
final_name=re.sub(r'_[0-9]+_', '_something_', name)
```

That's the basic regex constructs:`[0-9]` = one character, any of `0` to `9`; `+` = the previous has to appear one or more times. Note that `[0-9]` may match some odder characters too, depending on the locale and how Python implements that.

If you need to include negative or fractional numbers, you'll need to modify that.

Also note that `re.sub` substitutes all occurrences, not just the first. You could add `count=1` to only change the first matching one, but that still might not be between the first two underscores. In a sense, it may be better to split the string along the underscores, and then modify the second field thus found.